# component input with variable tags and text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, input, tags

I need an input component where I can insert text and when I enter a special character, a window appears with a choice of variables and it will be inserted as a tag, and this variable tag can be inserted anywhere in the text. As far as I understand, this should be done with contentEditable.

all I could do is such an input, where I put the $ symbol only at the end, and not a tag is added, but text:
[image]

I found many examples where there is just adding tags (https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/), but I didn’t find such a component where tags are mixed with text, can anyone see this?

```
import { useState } from 'react'

import classNames from 'classnames'
import ContentEditable from 'react-contenteditable'

import { useAppSelector } from '../../app/hooks'
import { selectVariables } from '../../redux/reducers/variables'

import styles from '../../stylesheets/components/common/InputVariable.module.scss'

export const InputVariable = ({ className, label, onChange, value }: any) => {
  const { variables } = useAppSelector(selectVariables)
  const [symbol, symbolSet] = useState(false)

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    const str = e.target.value

    onChange(str)

    if (str.charAt(str.length - 1) === '$') {
      symbolSet(true)
    } else {
      symbolSet(false)
    }
  }

  const handleClickVariable = (variable: any) => {
    const newStr = `${value.substring(0, value.length - 1)}{{${variable.id}}}`

    onChange(newStr)
    symbolSet(false)
  }

  const onPaste = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')

    console.log(text)
  }

  return (
    <div className={classNames(styles.inputVariable, className)}>
      <span className={styles.label}>{label}</span>
      <ContentEditable
        className={styles.root}
        html={value}
        disabled={false}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onPaste={onPaste}
      />
      {symbol && (
        <div className={styles.variables}>
          {variables &&
            variables.map((variable: any) => (
              <div key={variable.id} onClick={() => handleClickVariable(variable)} className={styles.variable}>
                {variable.name}
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default InputVariable
```

Comment: I tried looking for an existing component or pattern, and I'm guessting you'll have to implement it yourself. I managed to find this spec https://github.com/elastic/eui/issues/2756 in case it helps you to shape it.

Comment: thanks, but these are all pictures, there is no working example